# why my jquery is not working if i put the link

Tags: jquery

did not work modal popup why??

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>



<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.7/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<script>
    debugger;

    $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#modalLoginForm').modal('show');
    }, 3000); // milliseconds
});
</script>
```

did not open any modal at the set of the time period in the page

Comment: Show us your `modalLoginForm` html

Comment: put your code of `modal` and the place where you click to open the `modal`

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `bootstrap.min.css` run and try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#modalLoginForm').modal('show');
    }, 3000); // milliseconds
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalLoginForm" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Arunachala Prabhu happy to help, don't forget to mark the response as accepted to make it clear to future visitors ;)